# execute a linux echo command (.sh) in Php

Tags: php, linux, echo

I created a .sh file in my linux and want to run it from webpage (php + Apache).
Some of the simple example execute without problem. But I can't run with echo Pipe:

```
#!/bin/sh
set +v
cp /tmp/test/test1.tar.gz.gpg /tmp/test/ts2.gpg
echo 'myPassword' | /usr/bin/gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output /tmp/test/test1.tar.gz --decrypt /var/backups/test1.tar.gz.gpg

exit 0
```

It can copy ts2.gpg but can't run the second command (decrypt).

Comment: Does the user apache have rights to decrypt file `/var/backups/test1.tar.gz.gpg`?

Comment: Can you try --passphrase myPassword instead of --passphrase-fd 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You want shell_exec.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Enjoy